# C++, Qt: Only edit qtablewidgetitem after double click

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to know if there is a way to set up QTableWidget that the QTableWidgetItem can be changed just after double click?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I found something. I will use:  QTableWidget::setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers)

Comment: Since your answer is correct, I think you should write this comment as an answer instead (you can answer your own question so that it will be useful for others having the same issue). Moreover it may be useful to add that you also need to have the flag `Qt::ItemIsEditable` enabled for your `QTableWidgetItem` items (but I think it is enabled by default).

Comment: Thank you for the information about the flag, I will add my comment as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found something. I will use: QTableWidget::setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::EditTriggers).

As a comment of Fareanor in my question suggests: "it may be useful to add that you also need to have the flag Qt::ItemIsEditable enabled for your QTableWidgetItem items (but I think it is enabled by default)".